# Ruby counting duplicates in array and print into new file

Tags: ruby, arrays, duplicates

I need to count the number of duplicates in an array, find out how many times they appear and then put it into a document.. this is what I've done, and I am now clueless of how to proceed.... The data is from another txt file. I apologize if its a bit messy, but I am so confused right now.

```
class Ticket

attr_accessor :ticknum
attr_accessor :serialnum

    def initialize(ticknum,serialnum)
    @ticknum = ticknum
    @serialnum = serialnum

    end
end

class Ticketbook

    def initialize
    @ticketbook = Array.new
    end

    def newticket(ticket)
    @ticketbook << ticket
    @ticketbook.sort! {|x,y| x.ticknum*1000 + x.serialnum <=> y.ticknum*1000 + y.serialnum}

    end

    def soldnumber(tickenum2,serialnum2)
            @ticknum2 = ticknum2
            @serialnumb2 = serialnum2
            @antal = 0
        for i in 0..@ticketbook.length-1
        if @ticknum2 == @ticketbook[i].ticknum && @serialnum2 == @ticketbook[i].serialnum
            @antal +=1
        end
        end
        return @antal   
    end

end

ticketfile = File.open("tickets.txt", "r")

book = Ticketbook.new
ticketfile.each {|line| 
a = line.split(",")

newdoc = Ticket.new(a[0].to_i,a[1].to_i)
book.newticket(newdoc)
}

registernums = File.new("registernums.txt", "w")


for i in (0..@ticketbook.length-1)
registernums.print book[i].@ticketnum.to_i + ", "
registernums.print book[i].@serialnumber.to_i + ", "
registernums.puts book[i].soldnumber(i)
end
print registernums
```

gives me this error:
rb 56 unexpected tIVAR, expecting "(" registernums.print book[i].@ticketnum.to_i rb 57 unexpected tIVAR, expecting "(" registernums.print book[i].@serialnum.to_i

Comment: I can see what you've done but what's wrong with it?

Comment: it doesnt print anything into the new file, just gives me an error i cannot figure out how to solve

Comment: rb 56 unexpected tIVAR, expecting "(" registernums.print book[i].@ticketnum.to_i     rb 57 unexpected tIVAR, expecting "(" registernums.print book[i].@serialnum.to_i

Comment: Are you missing an `end` at the bottom?

Comment: yes it was missing in here, had it on my own file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop does not have a body so your last couple of lines reference `i` outside the loop where it is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with these lines.

```
registernums.print book[i].@ticketnum.to_i + ", "
registernums.print book[i].@serialnumber.to_i + ", "
```

To access any objects instance variables, you do not need to put an `@`. So the correct code should be

```
registernums.print book[i].ticketnum.to_i + ", "
registernums.print book[i].serialnumber.to_i + ", "
```

Also as @Jonah pointed out, there should be an `end` to end the last for loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here:

```
for i in (0..@ticketbook.length-1)
  registernums.print book[i].@ticketnum.to_i + ", "
  registernums.print book[i].@serialnumber.to_i + ", "
  registernums.puts book[i].soldnumber(i)
  print registernums
```

This code is outside the `TicketBook` class, so none of the instance variables (those beginning by `@`) are actually available.

If you want to access the array of tickets from outside the TicketBook, create an

```
attr_reader :ticketbook
```

in the `TicketBook` class.

You might want to replace your code by something like:

```
book.ticketbook.each_with_index do |tb, i|
  registernums.print tb.ticketnum.to_i + ", "
  registernums.print tb.ticketnum.to_i + ", "
  registernums.puts tb.soldnumber(i)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, boy!

Before I start few important points:
  - You are overusing instance variables - Ticket class is all right, but Ticketbook (should be TicketBook) should only have one instance_variable (the one set in initialize method), the rest should be local to method's scope.

- Ruby naming convention is to separate words with _ (new_doc, ticket_file and so on)
- You should almost never use `for` loop - the only reason to use it is to write your own iterator, but you are acting on arrays here - use `each` method

  - Use indentation!

Now about the errors:

```
ticketfile = File.open("tickets.txt", "r")

book = Ticketbook.new
ticketfile.each {|line| 
  a = line.split(",")

  newdoc = Ticket.new(a[0].to_i,a[1].to_i)
  book.newticket(newdoc)
}                                             

registernums = File.new("registernums.txt", "w")


for i in (0..@ticketbook.length-1)                       #  @ticketbook is an instance variable of Ticketbook, you'll get undefined length for nil:NilClass
registernums.print book[i].@ticketnum.to_i + ", "        # book is an instance of Ticketbook, [] is not defined on that class!
registernums.print book[i].@serialnumber.to_i + ", "
registernums.puts book[i].soldnumber(i)
print registernums
```

Your Ticketbook class

```
class Ticketbook

  def initialize
  @ticketbook = Array.new    #personaly would prefer []
  end

  def newticket(ticket)
  @ticketbook << ticket
  @ticketbook.sort! {|x,y| x.ticknum*1000 + x.serialnum <=> y.ticknum*1000 + y.serialnum}

  end

  def soldnumber(tickenum2,serialnum2)
        @ticknum2 = ticknum2           # unnecessary
        @serialnumb2 = serialnum2      # unnecessary
        @antal = 0
      for i in 0..@ticketbook.length-1      # Should be @ticketbook.each do |ticket|
      if @ticknum2 == @ticketbook[i].ticknum && @serialnum2 == @ticketbook[i].serialnum
          @antal +=1
      end
      end
      @antal

      # much better would be:
      # def soldnum(ticknum2, serialnum2)
      #   @ticketbook.select {|ticket| ticket.ticknum == ticknum2 && ticket.serialnum == serialnum }.count
      # end  

  end
```

end

I would also introduce you to `group_by` method - run on array will convert it into a really nice hash, where keys are result of executed block:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].group_by {|e| e.odd?} #=> {true => [1,3,5], false => [2,4,6]}
```

You can use it to get repetition count in one go:

```
# inside ticket book
def count_repetitions
  Hash[@ticketbook.group_by {|e| [e.ticknum, e.serialnum]}.map {|key, value| [key, value.count]}
end
```

This should return hash, where keys are two-element arrays containing ticknum and serialnum, and values are number of occurrences

Answer (score 0):

`tIVAR` refers to an instance variable, so the error message `unexpected tIVAR` means that ruby wasn't expecting an instance variable somewhere, and it points to this line (and the one after)

```
registernums.print book[i].@ticketnum.to_i + ", "
```

Accessing attributes in an object doesn't use the `@` character (and it isn't part of the variable name either). A correct way to access your `ticketnum` attribute is

```
registernums.print book[i].ticketnum.to_i + ", "
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question has been answered, I would like to suggest a more "Ruby-like" way of dealing with your problem.  First, a few points:

- A ticket as an object having two attributes: a ticket number and a serial number.  You could make a ticket an instance of a `Ticket` class, as you have done, a two-element array, with the understanding that the first and second elements correspond to the ticket and serial numbers, respectively, or as a hash, with one key for ticket number and another for serial number.  I favor a hash.  I see no need for separate class and I think the use of an array would be more likely to result in coding errors (e.g., if you used the wrong array element for a ticket or serial number).
- With all the methods Ruby provides in its [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) "mixin" module, there is no need to loop over indices.  Avoiding such loops will make your code more compact, easier to read and less likely to contain errors.
- As someone else mentioned, you do not need (any) instance variables.

We begin by adding some tickets to `ticketbook`:

```
ticketbook = []
ticketbook << {tnbr: 22, snbr: 55}
ticketbook << {tnbr: 27, snbr: 65}
ticketbook << {tnbr: 22, snbr: 56}
ticketbook << {tnbr: 27, snbr: 66}
  # => [{:tnbr=>22, :snbr=>55}, {:tnbr=>27, :snbr=>65}, \
        {:tnbr=>22, :snbr=>55}, {:tnbr=>27, :snbr=>65}]
```

Now to find duplicates (tickets having the same ticket number but different serial numbers).  Once you gain more experience with Ruby, you will think of the [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method (or possibly [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)) whenever you want to group elements of an array by some characteristic:

```
g0 = ticketbook.group_by {|t| t[:tnbr]}
  # => {22=>[{:tnbr=>22, :snbr=>55}, {:tnbr=>22, :snbr=>56}], \
  #     27=>[{:tnbr=>27, :snbr=>65}, {:tnbr=>27, :snbr=>66}]}
```

As you see, when we `group_by` ticket number, we obtain a hash with elements `(k,v)`, where the key `k` is a ticket number and the value `v` is an array of tickets (hashes) having that ticket number.

This may be all you need. If you want a count of the numbers of tickets having the same serial number, you could use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to convert each value in the `g0` hash (an array of tickets having the same ticket number) to the number of such tickets:

```
g1 = g0.map {|k,v| {k => v.size}} # => [{22=>2}, {27=>2}]
```

You might stop here, but it would be more convenient if this were instead a hash (`{22=>2, 27=>2}`), rather than an array of single-pair hashes.  There are several ways you can convert this array to a hash.  One is to use `map` to convert the hashes to arrays:

```
g2 = g1.map(&:to_a) # => [[[22, 2]], [[27, 2]]]
```

(where `map(&:to_a)` is shorthand for `map {|h| h.to_a}`) then use [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) to convert this to:

```
g3 = g2.flatten # => [22, 2, 27, 2]
```

One way to create a hash (in general) is like this:

```
Hash[1,2,3,4] # => {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

To do this with the array `g3` we need to prepend the array with the "splat" operator:

```
Hash[*g3] # => {22=>2, 27=>2}
```

This gives us the desired hash of counts by ticket number.  I said that was one way to convert an array of single-pair hashes to a hash.  Here is a more direct way:

```
g1.pop.merge(*g1) # => {27=>2, 22=>2}
```

Here `g1.pop` returns `{27=>2}` and converts `g1` to `[{22=>2}]`.  The above expression is therefore equivalent to:

```
{27=>2}.merge(*[{22=>2}]) # => {27=>2, 22=>2}
```

which merges the hashes in the splatted array (here just one) into the hash that precedes `merge`.

Rather than introducing the local variables `g0` and `g1`, you would normally "chain" these three operations:

```
ticketbook.group_by {|t| t[:tnbr]}.map {|k,v| {k => v.size}}.pop.merge(*g1)
  # => {27=>2, 22=>2}
```

Lastly, while your version of `sort` is fine, you could also do it like this:

```
ticketbook.sort! {|x,y| (x <=> y) == 0 ? x[:snbr] <=> y[:snbr] : \
  x[:tnbr] <=> y[:tnbr]}
```